# Unable to Connect Logitech MX Keys Mini to Ubuntu 22.04. Works in Try Ubuntu but Not in Installed Version

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, keyboard, driver, compatibility

I have a **Logitech MX Keys Mini** keyboard, and I want to connect it to my Ubuntu via Bluetooth. However, it doesn't work on the regular installed Ubuntu version that I have. I'm running **Ubuntu 22.04 Spanish version**, and it doesn't recognize any keyboard profiles. Strangely, in the **Try Ubuntu** version of **Ubuntu 22.04** on the same laptop with the default Bluetooth adapter, I can connect the keyboard without any issues. It recognizes all the keyboard profiles, and I can successfully connect and use it.

Additionally, I can connect the keyboard to Windows 11 and my iPhone. My laptop is an **MSI Thin GF63 12 VF**. Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried reinstalling the Ubuntu 22.04 operating system (several times) since the Try Ubuntu version of the same image works for me. I have been comparing details of the driver, drivers, error logs, and cannot find any apparent differences between the two versions. I am unsure if it is the drivers installed by Ubuntu during the disk installation, but I haven't found an apparent reason.

Comment: You'll probably have better luck asking in https://askubuntu.com/